# Signing Error when uploading to iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, cordova, certificate, phonegap-plugins, ios-provisioning

I am getting an error that my app has not been signed by a distribution certificate when I am uploading to iTunes Connect with the application loader...
Here are the steps that I am taking:

```
1. Create CSR file in KeyChain Access
2. Create Distribution Certificate
3. Create Provisioning profile relating to the distribution cert
4. I am building the app with PHONEGAP
5. Uploading .ipa file to iTunesConnect
```

What am I doing wrong? I have gone through steps online to sign your app and I am following them correctly.. But I am still getting this error.. Does it have to do with phone gap?

Here is the error:
[image]

Comment: You say you are building the app, but are you actually signing it?

Comment: phonegap apps require the app the be signed... I add the .p12 file and provisioning profile to the .zip file that I am building...

Comment: If there is an error log I would recommend including it in your question.

Comment: okay, doing that now

Comment: 1. You may already check but still can you confirm that you have selected Appstore when generating profile and not Adhoc.

2. If you are trying to upload IPS from Xcode, then new Xcode will do everything for you (Generating certificate, profile and etc...) so may be you can try out that.

Answer (score 0):

I met same issue when I used command to build, export and upload (this issue appear in xcodetool too). This is the way I fixed it:

1. Open KeyChain Access
2. Click on your Certification and change Trust to `Use System Default`
3. Click on Key of Certification and set Access to "Allow all application.."